# How do I implement selector for actionbar?

Tags: android, selector

I have an actionBar, I would like the text color to change depending on the state each menuItem is in.

- Pressed: Yellow text
- Focus: blue text 
  etc.

I've created my selector and a color resource, Im just not sure how to implement it with my actionBar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:color="@color/pink" android:state_pressed="true" />
   <item android:color="@color/blue" android:state_focused="true" />
   <item android:color="@color/yellow" />
 </selector>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
  <color name="green">#7AB800</color>
  <color name="blue">#00B0CA</color>
  <color name="yellow">#FDC82F</color>
  <color name="pink">#DC0451</color>
  <color name="orange">#F78F1E</color>
  <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```